What is the different of Box<closure> and closure?
let mut x = 10;
let mut closure: Box<dyn FnMut() -> i32> = Box::new(|| {
    println!("x = {}", x);
    x += 5;
    x
});

let value1 = closure(); // x = 10
let value2 = closure(); // x = 15
let value3 = closure(); // x = 20
println!(
    "value1 = {}, value2 = {}, value3 = {}",
    value1, value2, value3
);
// println!("After closure call, x = {}", x); // error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

let mut x = 10;
let mut closure = || {
    println!("x = {}", x);
    x += 5;
    x
};

let value1 = closure(); // x = 10
let value2 = closure(); // x = 15
let value3 = closure(); // x = 20
println!(
    "value1 = {}, value2 = {}, value3 = {}",
    value1, value2, value3
);
println!("After closure call, x = {}", x); // x is ok for printing.

My questions:

what type of closure in 2nd code?

Why closure wrapped by Box pointer in first code is different with closure alone in second one?

How can i use x after closure? the right way is?



Why not pass the x as parameter into the closure? So x is no longer borrowed, if the closure is finished and x can be used after the closure.


what type of closure in 2nd code?
As documented in the Rust Reference chapter on Closure Types:

A closure expression produces a closure value with a unique, anonymous type that cannot be written out.


Why closure wrapped by Box pointer in first code is different with closure alone in second one?
Both closures exclusively borrow x.  So long as they're "alive", x cannot be accessed from elsewhere.
Prior to Rust v1.63, both closures remained alive until the end of the lexical scope—causing their borrows of x also to continue beyond your println! statements.  However, thanks to non-lexical lifetimes, Rust is now able to determine that closure ceases to be alive (and its borrows end) after its last use.
In the non-Box case, closure is last used in the assignment to value3.
In the Box case, closure is last used when it is destroyed (implicitly at the end of the lexical scope): Box has a Drop handler (that frees its heap allocation) that could theoretically make use of the exclusive borrow of x.  Therefore, in that case, closure's borrows must continue until then.

How can i use x after closure? the right way is?
Once you've finished using closure, you could explicitly drop(closure);.  Its exclusive borrow of x would then end, permitting you to use x again thereafter.



That's not the Box who has a drop (it's #[may_dangle]) but the dyn FnMut.

@ChayimFriedman: my understanding of #[may_dangle] was always that it allows dropck to relax the requirement that the Box strictly outlive its type parameter.  Besides, surely dyn FnMut doesn't drop: if a closure has anything that needs to be destructed, wouldn't it necessarily be a FnOnce?

It does both. And FnMut can definitely have a destructor if it moves something that is Drop. Also, you can try for yourself and see.

But a FnMut cannot move something that is Drop, can it?  My attempt.

@eggyal the problem isn't moving something that is Drop into the FnMut, the problem is that foo; causes it to be dropped the first time the closure is invoked, thus making multiple calls impossible. If you don't drop it nor move it out, it works: playground

Okay.  I think I'm with it now.  But take a look at this: neither closure is actually dropped until the end of the lexical scope, but NLL permits the borrow of x1 to end sooner than the borrow of x2.  Is this because closures are special in the compiler, and it knows that their drop handlers won't use any borrows that they hold; whereas it doesn't know that about a dyn FnMut?  Or else what is going on here?  @Jmb @ChayimFriedman

That's interesting; I believe closures are internally marked by the compiler as #[may_dangle] because they can have no drop impl.
